# Cannot print data into "view"

Tags: php, arrays, function, codeigniter

I have a page that I would like to show the data from the database.

I can `print_r($sale)` and it shows the data that I am after - $sale is set in the controller  but I cannot seem to do `<?php $sale['name'] ?>` it shows nothing.

**Print_r**:

```
Array ( [0] => stdClass Object ( [id] => 48 [name] => Jess McKenzie [location] => Auckland [bedrooms] => 5 [bathrooms] => 1 [condition] => Fair [description] =>
hii
[price] => 30.00000 [imagename] => purple.jpg [thumbname] => purple_thumb.jpg ) [1] => stdClass Object ( [id] => 49 [name] => jzmwebdevelopment [location] => Auckland [bedrooms] => 15 [bathrooms] => 4 [condition] => OK [description] =>
zebra
[price] => 25.00000 [imagename] => Zebra.jpg [thumbname] => Zebra_thumb.jpg ) )
```

**Model**:

```
function getSalesContent($id = NULL) {
    $this->db->where('id', $id);
    $query = $this->db->get('sales', 1);

    if($query->num_rows() > 0) {
        $row = $query->result_array();
        return $row;
    }else{
        return FALSE;
    } # End IF
} # End getSalesContent
```

Comment: could you post the result of print_r($sale)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's returning an array of objects.

To show the first element returned you would use

```
$sale[0]->name;
```

To cycle through all of the values you could use a foreach loop

```
foreach($sale as $s){
    print $s->name;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`$query->result_array()` returns an array of arrays, you would use `$sale['name']` in a foreach loop.

`$query->result()` returns an array of stdclass objects, you would use `$sale->name` in a foreach loop.

> I cannot seem to do $sale->name it
>   shows nothing.

Open your `index.php` file and add `error_reporting(E_ALL)` to the top. If you were error reporting you'd be able to see your mistakes with helpful error messages telling you exactly what went wrong. Just set it to `0` for when you go live.

> I have tried `<?php $sale['name'] ?>` and get nothing

You need an `echo` statement: `<?php echo $sale['name'] ?>`

If `$sale` is the output you posted, `<?php echo $sale[0]->name ?>` should print `Jess McKenzie`

Comment: @Wesley That gives me a white page

Comment: @Jess: I have no idea then. I'm assuming you probably just have lots of errors. You should investigate some basic debugging techniques.